# GET , POST , PUT , DELETE type based Authentication in keycloak

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, keycloak

I have a resource in an API for which URI is `/product/{id}` and doing three operations `VIEW, GET, DELETE` basse on `HttpMethod`.

How can I manage one user is allowed to only `VIEW` and `admin` is allowed to `VIEW, GET, DELETE` i.e. all options.

I had seen `Keycloak Adapter Policy Enforcer` but, I don't understand how it works.
I am not getting methods option in create permission.

Can somebody help me in implementing this or suggest some way to do it.

Comment: Where do you want to place your authorization? In a database? And then you want to determine at runtime who is allowed to do what?

Comment: No I want to place my authorization in url and method type . If I will use same url like /products/{id} for edit , delete and get single product . There method type is different for edit method type is put , for delete I have used method type delete then how I can manage Authorization using keycloak . I have implement role-based authentication But now I want uri based Authentication

Answer (score 5):

I guess you installed Keycloak for being able to control not just authentication, but also authorization. Then you don't need spring security at all. You need to enable authorization for your client and configure resources, policies and permissions using Keycloak admin console. Here is [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html)

To be able to control your resources more granular use policy enforcers and map HTTP methods to scopes like described here: [How to add HTTP methods in Keycloak resources for Authorization (Without adapters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62323931/how-to-add-http-methods-in-keycloak-resources-for-authorization-without-adapter).

One of the good examples worth to look at is [authz-spring-boot](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-authz-rest-springboot). It has complete authorization flow, but without method restriction that can be manually added.

You also can check how does your policy work using "Evalute" tab at Keycloak. This simulates client call to the resource and shows the result

Comment: method + URI is not mentioned in docs. Can you please show example ?

Comment: first, you should enable authorization for your client. Then "Authorization" menu appears.
second, you go to Authorization->Resources-> Create new Filter.
Under Filter URIS you can put you URI + method. For example "POST /api/*". Under actions you will define associated permissions. For example user or group that can execute this POST

Comment: Very useful functionality is "Evaluate" menu. Use it for testing. You can select user, client, resource and see whether it passes your rules or not.

Comment: This is not mentioned in docs, indeed, but I found it somewhere in examples. Tested and it worked.

Comment: I seted up the app-authz-rest-springboot example. Then I'm adding the method at the beginning of the URI as you mention "GET /api/{resource}" but i'm getting a 403 error. Besides adding "GET" in the URI do I have to modify something else?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, @RicardoCampos. I double-checked this example and found my reply was not exactly correct. To define resource method authorization you need first to enable policy enforcer like described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62323931/how-to-add-http-methods-in-keycloak-resources-for-authorization-without-adapter
Then you can define methods as scopes at client->authorization-authorization scopes
After that you can use this scopes together with URI to filter your requests based on HTTP methods

Answer (score 1):

What you need is spring security. You can add it to your project using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You could define your security settings like this (I'm assuming that other configuration is already done):

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

// ...

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                //HTTP Basic authentication
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/product/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/product").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/product/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/product/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/product/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable();
      }
}
```

Comment: NO, that's not what SO user wants. according to your code only USER can access the `/product/** `with `GET`. Admin will not be able to do `GET`, that's not the functionality user wants.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the best suitable option is to use annotation based policy michanisam.
so before each and every rest service you need to write its access policy, for example :

```
@Secured("ROLE_VIEWER")
public String getUsername() {
    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    return securityContext.getAuthentication().getName();
}
```

So as you can see the getUsername() method will be only allowed by the viewer.

```
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
public boolean isValidUsername(String username) {
     return userRoleRepository.isValidUsername(username);
}
```

So as you see the above method will only allow to be accessed by admin, the same annotation can be used for rest services as well. to use this facelity you need to integrate spring security with your spring boot application.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

For more detail you can check out this artical, but i do see this is the best way to control the data security and the service security in a spring boot application.

Reference : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security

Comment: Thank you! But I dont want role based Authantication . I want Url and method type based authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. The following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62323931/how-to-add-http-methods-in-keycloak-resources-for-authorization-without-adapter/62336367#62336367) provides the explanation.

Thus, you can define the HTTP methods as scopes and check for permission via the [following Keycloak API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_service_obtaining_permissions).

```sh
curl -X POST \
  http://${host}:${port}/auth/realms/${realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}" \
  --data "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket" \
  --data "audience={resource_server_client_id}" \
  --data "permission=Resource A#GET"
```