# How to add HTTP methods in Keycloak resources for Authorization (Without adapters)

Tags: keycloak

When using Keycloak for authorization it allows creating protected resources. But it only allows defining the URI. How can I also add the HTTP method for the resource?

Although it seems the [policy enforcers](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_enforcer_overview) allows us to define such details, how is Keycloak able to map the HTTP method with the resource?

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: Could you solve this problem? if yes, can you share the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want scopes to be mapped to HTTP methods then you need to set `http-method-as-scope` to true.

You can check policy enforcer documentation [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_enforcer_filter)

With spring-boot adapter you can set `keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.http-method-as-scope=true` and your resources would be associated with scopes such as GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so I assume when implementing without adapters, I should define scopes as HTTP methods and from the front end send the HTTP methods as scope checks.